# Storing a document on Firestore: detect if the operation is successful on the server, locally or unsuccessful?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Java Android application using Google Firestore. When the user creates data, they have to be stored on Firestore (the user clicks on a "submit" button). The application displays a ProgressBar until either the storage is successful or fails. How to detect data are stored (either locally or on the remote server) ? I would like to tell the user if the storage is successful (data stored on the server), successful locally (server unreachable, but offline storage is ok) or unsuccessful.

For completion of the storage on the server, it is easy to detect this with the registration of an OnCompleteListener on the Task.

But when the server is unreachable, the listener is not called (in fact, it is called later when the server is reachable again, but the user cannot wait so long !). I found it is possible to be notified data are stored locally with an EventListener registered on the DocumentReference. This listener can get info with documentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache() and documentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites(). But this listener is notified also when the server is online and data are stored on the server.

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 final DocumentReference documentReference =
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(documentFirestorePath);
 documentReference. addSnapshotListener(this, MetadataChanges.INCLUDE,
 new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onEvent(@Nullable final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable final FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
         Log.i("MyActivity", "isFromCache: "+documentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()+", write pending:
 "+documentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites());
     } });
 documentReference.set(newContact).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<Void> task) {
         Log.i("MyActivity", "completed");
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             finish();
         } else {
             // Inform the customer the action failed
         }
     }
  });
```

Here are the logs when the server is online:

```
2019-06-13 08:11:14.126 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: true, write pending: false
2019-06-13 08:11:14.170 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: true, write pending: true
2019-06-13 08:11:14.218 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: false, write pending: true
2019-06-13 08:11:14.470 I/MyActivity: completed
2019-06-13 08:11:14.552 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: false, write pending: false
```

And the logs when the server is offline:

```
2019-06-13 08:12:08.185 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: true, write pending: false
2019-06-13 08:12:08.215 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: true, write pending: true
And when the server is back, the following logs are added:
2019-06-13 08:12:40.460 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: false, write pending: true
2019-06-13 08:12:40.671 I/MyActivity: completed
2019-06-13 08:12:40.753 I/MyActivity: isFromCache: false, write pending: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is enough to tell the user his modifications are stored (either locally or on the server).

So

```
addSnapshotListener(this, MetadataChanges.INCLUDE,
 new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
```

is sufficient : the condition to check is hasPendingWrites == true.

No need for an OnCompleteListener.